# Using Simplex for Difference Logic

Tags: lo.logic, sat, simplex

I'm interested in what happens when using the Simplex algorithm on Difference logic, inspired by problem 5.4 in Kroening and Strichman's *Decision Procedures*.

Clearly, in this case, all constraints of the program will have only two variables, with coefficients 1 and -1, so the matrix will be of a special type. What happens when running the Simplex algorithm on such a program? Is it easier to solve?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you sketch in a few words what you mean by *difference logic* for readers without access to Kroening & Strichman?